# Stop match at first occurence of character, or continue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input like this:

- "Some string (parens)"
- "Some string"

I want to get everything before the first parens, or just everything if there are none

I've tried this:

```
(.+)(?=\()
```

But that only works when there are parens, obviously.
Then I tried this:

```
(.+)(?=\()?
```

But that just selects everything.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex as

```
^[^(]+
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `[^(]` Matches anything other than `(` . Quantifier `+` matches one or more occurence of the presceding regex

[**Regex demo link**](https://regex101.com/r/pG0uG1/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex.

```
^[^(]*
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start and `[^(]*` matches any character but not of `(` zero or more times. `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pG0uG1/2)

Comment: this matches an empty string if the input is like `(foo)` . But yours will fail.

Comment: But from what OP wrote he expects something before the paranthesis `(.+)(?=\()?`